# VK API для проигрывания музыки

Tags: vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте! Как можно получить доступ ко всем аудиозаписям VK с возможностью проигрывания их на своём сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Уже правильно дали ссылку на [audio.*](https://vk.com/dev/audio) методы api – можно сделать и [поиск](https://vk.com/dev/audio.search) и [проигрывание](https://vk.com/dev/audio.get) любой аудиозаписи из недр ВКонтакте.

Есть одно «но»: для вызова этих методов надо давать разрешение какого-то пользователя ВК. Если вы благородно дадите разрешение собственного аккаунта и сохраните токен, на вашем сайте любой посетитель сможет слушать музыку из ВК «от вашего имени». А тут действуют серьёзные ограничения, напр. не более 3 запросов в секунду.

Альтернатива – давать возможность слушать на сайте, предварительно авторизовав каждого посетителя через ВК. Но зачем им такой «функционал», спрашивается?

Answer (score 0):

Ко всем аудиозаписям доступ Вы не получите.

Но можно например получить доступ к популярным - http://vk.com/dev/audio.getPopular

Comment: Странно, Дуров говорил мне, когда я был молодым: "Юзай audio.* и все получится". Для поиска используйте audio.search, audio.get - если хотите получить записи пользователя. Все audio.* методы позволят вам получить полный доступ к аудиозаписям, дерзайте.

Comment: Ему надо именно ко всем аудиозаписям. Вся музыка, что есть во ВКонтакте. Такого метода я не встречал.

Comment: @ModaL - так вот же все по аудио - https://vk.com/dev/audio